# Have ceiling damage in daughter’s college condo shower area..can I fix?

Tags: ceiling

[image]

My daughter has had this for over a year, it ‘feels’ dry, don’t think additional damage has occurred. My dear friend owns the condo, has 11 children, and gives us a great deal so I try to help out with repairs, I fix towel bars, ceiling fan wiring, toilet repairs, etc. 
can I scrape this off and just kilz over it until she can get a ceiling guy in? I really don’t want to replace backer board on a ceiling. Any recommendations?

Comment: Looks like moisture from behind damage. What is over this spot.

Comment: you can "clone" the texture with putty from a good spot, then use the "mold" to texturize a thin coat of plaster where you removed the original texture.

Answer (score 1):

I think your plan is fine, assuming there isn't a persistent plumbing issue. I'd gently brush and scrape away just the loose material, striving to retain as much texture as possible. If it gets smooth, dab on some spackle or joint compound to replicate the texture, then prime and paint.

Recognize that your paint probably won't match the existing very well, so keep it small and feather it in.